# Convertor for complex type to bind in asp .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, data-conversion

I Use `Persian Datetime` in my project. I installed a library from `nuget` to convert my date.

this is my model :

```
public class Patient
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string FName { get; set; }
        public string LName { get; set; }
        public PersianDateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
}
```

this is my view:

```
    @model MyProject.Models.Patient
    @{
            Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
        }
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/md.bootstrappersiandatetimepicker/dist/jquery.md.bootstrap.datetimepicker.style.css" />
    
    
    <hr />
    <div class="container card border-dark">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <form asp-action="Edit">
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="FName" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="FName" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="FName" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="LName" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="LName" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="LName" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text cursor-pointer" id="date3">Icon</span>
                    </div>
                    <input asp-for="BirthDate" id="ff" class="form-control" aria-label="date3" aria-describedby="date3">
                </div>
<div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
    </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

it works when I open the page and all inputs get filled
but when I want to edit them `BirthDate` field get wrong value
this is cod in my controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(long id, [Bind("Id,FName,LName,BirthDate")] Patient patient)
        {
           
            if (id != patient.Id)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(patient);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!PatientExists(patient.Id))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }

            return View(patient);
        }
```

I understand that `PersianDateTime` have a property `Date` that just have get method, I figured that when I get `BirthDate` as a `string` parameter it has correct string value but when it is going to get as `PersianDateTime` it has wrong Value. `PersianDateTime` has a method that `parse` `string` and return a `PersianDateTime`, but I want to know how can I use a convertor that all my pages use that and `BirthDate` can bind to model

Comment: One way to handle this is by creating a custom model binder class that implements the ```IModelBinder``` interface and hooking it up in the Startup.cs through the ```IModelBinderProvider```. Have you given a thought about this?

Comment: I think that if PersianDateTime is directly passed back to the controller as a field, this should not be possible.
If allowed, I suggest you add a `DateTime` field to the model to receive the date, and then convert the date into PersianDateTime in the controller.
In this regard, you need to use ajax to pass data to ensure that the passed parameters are correct. If you accept this solution and still have questions, please let me know and I will provide you with an example.